# How to make my python code more effective?

Tags: python, nlp, n-gram

I am constructing my word n-gram training vector later to be used by `SVM`. I ran my code, but it took me too much time, above 10 hours. Do you have any method to make it faster?

```
def wordNgrams(s,n):
    """Calculate word n-grams and return a dictionary"""
    input = s.split(' ')
    output = {}
    for i in xrange(len(input)-n+1):
        g = " ".join(input[i:i+n]).lower()
        output.setdefault(g,0)
        output[g] += 1
    return output
```

`res` is a `list` of 10000 strings, whereas each string contains 300 words on average. `global_vector` is a sorted `list` of 200000 2-grams.

```
X = []
for i in xrange(10000):
     word_dic = wordNgrams(res[i], 2)
     vector1 = {key : 1 if key in word_dic else 0 for key in global_vector}
     od = OrderedDict(sorted(vector1.items(), key = lambda t : t[0]))
     X.append(od.values())
```

To be honest, it is common if it takes 2 or 3 hours. But it took me over 10 hours. I really do not what I should do. Please help me.

Comment: This doesn't seem very useful. The values that you're appending to `X` will be not be in any particular order (dictionaries are not ordered). I'm not sure what an arbitrarily ordered list of lists of `0`s and `1`s is good for. Can you clarify what specifically the output is supposed to be?

Comment: I have edited the problem. What I want to do is to add vectors of 0s and 1s corresponding to a sorted word n-gram list global_vector. But it took me over 10 hours. Could you give me a more effective method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `sorted` call you are running in your loop is the only thing that can be optimized out. Everything else appears to be asymptotically optimal (it may be possible to improve things by small factors in various places, but not by huge amounts).

If your `global_vector` is already sorted, you can avoid sorting the results by creating the results list directly, rather than going through an unordered dictionary first. Here's a quick version that uses a list comprehension:

```
X = []
for text in res:
    word_dic = wordNgrams(text, 2)
    X.append([1 if bigram in word_dic else 0 for bigram in global_vector])
```

This should be `O(M*N) + O(M*P)` where `M` is the length of `res`, `N` is the length of `global_vector` and `P` is the average length of the texts. Your original code included an extra `log(N)` factor in the first term, due to the extra sorting.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. what you mean is I do not need to sort the vector1 dictionary?

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thank you very much. But could you please explain to me that why I do not need to sort the dictionary vector1? Are these vectors in X corresponding right order with global_vector?

Comment: @wanglan8498: Using the dictionary discarded the order you had in `global_vector`. But you never really needed the dictionary in the first place. Just go directly from one list (`global_vector`) to another (the list of `0`s and `1`s).